# How do I avoid creating long and complicated sequence diagrams?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I'm very new at creating sequence diagrams. I've been watching countless videos of tutorials to make sure I understand the concept, however, the trouble starts when I have to implement a specific dice game  between 2 players into a sequence diagram without making it too long and complicated. I say specific dice game since there's custom rules added to it. This leads to many alternative scenarios and loops. Do I only include the most important parts of the dice game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, only show what's needed. That would be parts where for example many objects communicate. You never show the full path (which is impossible anyway for almost all cases). SDs are not for graphical programming. They shall help to give you the ideas of certain collaborations. So create as many SDs as needed starting with just some basics. When questions come up you can use additional SDs to clarify these. Also relate SDs to the collaborations (being realizations of use cases). Depending on the tool you use there are different ways to do that (packing would be one of them).